# R Treemap - how to add multiple labels

Tags: r, label, treemap

I'm trying to create a treemap using R package treemap similar to the one in a sample from the package.

```
library(treemap)
data(GNI2010)
treemap(GNI2010,
    index=c("iso3"),
    vSize="population",
    vColor="GNI",
    type="value")
```

Is there any way to add extra labels from columns to display "CHN, 1,35 bln, 20% "

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a new variable, such as "label" below, and with `paste` or `sprintf` and various format choices for digits, etc., craft whatever label you want.  Then use that variable instead of iso3.  You will run out of space on the smaller rectangles but there is the `force.print.labels` argument to invoke.

Here is a simple example that adds the population.[image]

```
GNI2010$label <- paste(GNI2010$iso3, GNI2010$population, sep = ", ")

treemap(GNI2010,
        index=c("label"),
        vSize="population",
        vColor="GNI",
        type="value")
```

Comment: The package has beeen updated, the dataset is named now GNI2014. So, the code is: 
data(GNI2014)
treemap(GNI2014,
        [etc])

Answer (score 6):

Following lawyeR answer, but adding a detail. If you want to center both labels one above the other, use "\n" as separator in paste function

```
GNI2010$label <- paste(GNI2010$iso3, GNI2010$population, sep = "\n")

treemap(GNI2010,
    index=c("label"),
    vSize="population",
    vColor="GNI",
    type="value")
```